# Which Bitcoin mixer has the largest pool of customers?

Tags: privacy

As the title of the post states, which current Bitcoin mixer has the largest pool of customers?

I understand that the larger the customer base of a Bitcoin mixer, the more anonymity the mixer will provide.

Comment: I don't think many pools share that kind of information. I believe blockchain.info's mixer service has a good bunch of users.

Comment: Voted to Leave Closed: This question is off-topic, as it is pertaining to current market values and service provider availability.

Answer (score 1):

you can always send coins to silkroad and withdraw them. i would think that they have a large pool since basically all coins that go through there get washed

Comment: How do I get to SilkRoad? Does it require verification, like identification papers?